# Product images don't show on frontend, cache folder not building

Tags: cache

Product images are not showing up on the front end of my install.  They show up fine on the backend, but on the front end it shows the placeholder image instead.

Things I have already tried

- Media folder set to 777 recursively
- Made sure gd library is installed with jpg support
- Delete .htaccess, delete cache folder, flush caches, etc
- I believe I have the correct owner on the media folder, I ran a php script to create a new file and it created the file with my ftp user, so I assume that's who the owner of the media folder should be?
- Made sure radio buttons are selected on product images page for base image, small image, etc
- PHP memory limit is set to 512M
- images are at max 60kb, with no spaces in the image name
- Checked error logs, can't find anything relevant

Since deleting the cache folder and .htaccess file, neither is being recreated in the media folder.  When I upload the image it shows up properly in the media folder (for instance if I upload necklace.jpg it shows up in media/catalog/product/n/e/necklace.jpg as well as the three additional resized images).

I am totally at a loss at this point.  Any more suggestions out there?

Magento version 1.8.0.0

Comment: What is your Magento version?

Comment: It is Magento version 1.8.0.0